# Create a unique list of names based on criteria

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I've attempted to use the formulas on the sheet found at the following address as the base of my report.

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/03/create-a-list-of-distinct-values-from-a-list-where-an-adjacent-cell-value-meets-a-criteria-in-excel/

After downloading I can see that it does work but when I click on the cell H2's formula to better view what cells are used in it, it breaks and gives a #N/A error. I creating a new spreadsheet and tried using this

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($C$2:$C$16,MATCH(0,IF($F$1=$B$2:$B$16,COUNTIF($H$1:$H1,$C$2:$C$16),""),0))), 1, 1)
```

which works in Google docs but is removed from it when opened in Excel.

All these issues happen both on my home computer and work computer. Both are running Excel 2007.

Comment: You need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter after editing the formula in Excel instead of just Enter..  It makes it an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

The ARRAY_CONSTRAIN() and ARRAYFORMULA() are not excel functions.  It is used in Google Docs alone.

ARRAYFORMULA() can be removed and replaced with CTRL+Shift+Enter in excel.

ARRAY_CONSTRAIN() Constrains an array result to a specified size. I don't know any formula to do that in excel apart from Index Function.